dot indexing is not supported in MATLAB
I am trying to simulate the arduino braccio robot in the matlab for a simple pick and place task, here is the complete code for that:
clear; clc; close all;

%% Step 1: Define the Braccio Robot Model

% Create a rigid body tree model
robot = robotics.RigidBodyTree('DataFormat', 'column', 'MaxNumBodies', 6);

% Define base
body1 = robotics.RigidBody('link1');
jnt1 = robotics.Joint('jnt1', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt1, trvec2tform([0, 0, 0.1]));  % Adjust height as needed
jnt1.HomePosition = 0;
body1.Joint = jnt1;
addBody(robot, body1, 'base');  % Adding link1 to the base

% Define link2, link3, link4, link5, and gripper (similar to link1)
% Define link2
body2 = robotics.RigidBody('link2');
jnt2 = robotics.Joint('jnt2', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt2, trvec2tform([0.1, 0, 0]));  % Adjust length as needed
jnt2.HomePosition = 0;
body2.Joint = jnt2;
addBody(robot, body2, 'link1');

% Define link3
body3 = robotics.RigidBody('link3');
jnt3 = robotics.Joint('jnt3', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt3, trvec2tform([0.1, 0, 0]));  % Adjust length as needed
jnt3.HomePosition = 0;
body3.Joint = jnt3;
addBody(robot, body3, 'link2');

% Define link4
body4 = robotics.RigidBody('link4');
jnt4 = robotics.Joint('jnt4', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt4, trvec2tform([0.1, 0, 0]));  % Adjust length as needed
jnt4.HomePosition = 0;
body4.Joint = jnt4;
addBody(robot, body4, 'link3');

% Define link5
body5 = robotics.RigidBody('link5');
jnt5 = robotics.Joint('jnt5', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt5, trvec2tform([0.1, 0, 0]));  % Adjust length as needed
jnt5.HomePosition = 0;
body5.Joint = jnt5;
addBody(robot, body5, 'link4');

% Define gripper
body6 = robotics.RigidBody('gripper');
jnt6 = robotics.Joint('jnt6', 'revolute');
setFixedTransform(jnt6, trvec2tform([0.05, 0, 0]));  % Adjust length as needed
jnt6.HomePosition = 0;
body6.Joint = jnt6;
addBody(robot, body6, 'link5');

% Show the robot model
showdetails(robot);
show(robot);
title('Braccio Robot Model');
pause(2);

%% Step 2: Simulate Pick-and-Place Task

% Define the initial and target poses
initialPose = trvec2tform([0.1, 0.0, 0.1]);  % Initial position
targetPose = trvec2tform([0.2, 0.1, 0.2]);   % Target position

% Inverse kinematics solver
ik = robotics.InverseKinematics('RigidBodyTree', robot);
weights = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 1, 1];
initialGuess = robot.homeConfiguration;

% Solve for the initial configuration
[configSol, ~] = ik('gripper', initialPose, weights, initialGuess);

% Display the robot in initial pose
show(robot, configSol);
title('Initial Pose');
drawnow;
pause(2);

% Solve for the target configuration
[configSol, ~] = ik('gripper', targetPose, weights, initialGuess);

% Display the robot in target pose
show(robot, configSol);
title('Target Pose');
drawnow;
pause(2);

%% Step 3: Integrate Model Predictions (Optional)

% Main loop with simulated predictions
pickX = 0.1;
pickY = 0.0;
placeX = 0.2;
placeY = 0.1;

% Get simulated model predictions
angles = getModelPredictions(pickX, pickY, placeX, placeY);

% Initialize predictedConfig as an array of JointState objects
predictedConfig = repmat(robot.homeConfiguration, length(angles), 1);

% Apply the predicted angles to the robot configuration
for i = 1:length(angles)
  % Set joint position for each body
  predictedConfig(i).JointPosition = angles(:, i);
end

% Display the robot with predicted angles
show(robot, predictedConfig);
title('Predicted Angles Pose');
drawnow;
pause(2);

%% Function Definitions

% Example function to simulate getting predictions from a model
function angles = getModelPredictions(~, ~, ~, ~)
  % Simulate model predictions
  angles = [0.5, 0.25, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1];  % Example values
end

and this is the error I am getting
Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in rigidbody (line 110)
    predictedConfig(i).JointPosition = angles(:, i);
 

I kept getting this error, I don't understand is it because of the the for loop variable or something related to the robot description.

Please read [mre], don’t dump all your code here.

Add a breakpoint and look at what predictedConfig(i) is, you're trying to use dot-indexing as if it's a struct, table, or object with specific fields/props, but I assume it's empty or numeric or some other type which does not support dot-indexing as the error suggests.

The problem here is that as written, robot.homeConfiguration is returning a numeric vector. Therefore, when you say
predictedConfig = repmat(robot.homeConfiguration, length(angles), 1);

you are ending up with another numeric vector. As such, predictedConfig does not have a field JointPosition, which is precisely what the error message is telling you.
To fix this problem, I think you need to set the DataFormat of your robot to be 'struct', as this will then cause homeConfiguration to return a struct. In other words:
% Create a rigid body tree model
robot = robotics.RigidBodyTree('DataFormat', 'struct', 'MaxNumBodies', 6);

You then have further work to do to fix up the remaining code. With DataFormat='struct', your predictedConfig will then be a 6x6 structure array. This probably isn't what you intend, but I'm not sure what you need here. For instance, you might need to do this to fix the call to show:
show(robot, predictedConfig(1,:));

